# How to get the images depending on the position in getView of CustomAdapter using Horizontal ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using Horizontal Listview to display the four images in a screen fitted, such that these images will be obtained from Database.

My main.xml is as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.test.hlistview.HorizListview
        android:id="@+id/hlvSimpleList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity class is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    HorizListview hlist;
    private int[] imageid = new int[] { R.drawable.lion, R.drawable.love,
            R.drawable.android, R.drawable.handshake };
    private String[] imagename = new String[] { "Lion", "Love", "Android",
            "Handshake" };
    List<Details> additems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        hlist = (HorizListview) findViewById(R.id.hlvSimpleList);
        additems = new ArrayList<Details>();
        Log.i("Length of array", "size is" + imagename.length);
        int length = imagename.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Details det = new Details(imageid[i], imagename[i]);
            additems.add(det);

        }

        CAdapter c = new CAdapter(this, additems);
        hlist.setAdapter(c);

    }
}
```

I have imageview and Textview in a tablelayout , that xml is as follows which i named as photo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mymilan_circle_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mymilan_circle_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mymilan_circle_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mymilan_circle_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Now my custom Adapter class is as follows.

```
public class CAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Details> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Details> item;
    private Context con;
    private int newpostion;

    public CAdapter(Context context, List<Details> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.photo, objects);
        this.con = context;
        this.item = objects;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size()/4;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        newpostion = 0 * position;
        newpostion = 0 * position+1;
        newpostion = 0 * position+2;
        newpostion = 0 * position+3;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // Inflate the view since it does not exist
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo, parent, false);

            // Create and save off the holder in the tag so we get quick access to inner fields
            // This must be done for performance reasons
            holder = new Holder();
            Log.i("VIEW HOLDER", "Position is" + newpostion);
            holder.trow = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row1);
            holder.trow2 = (TableRow) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row2);

            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image1);
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            holder.thirdimage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image3);
            holder.ttextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            holder.secondimage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image2);
            holder.stextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            holder.fourthimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image4);
            holder.ftextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Details det = (Details) getItem(newpostion);
        for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
            if(i ==0){
                holder.textview.setText(det.getImgname());
                holder.image.setBackgroundResource(det.getImgid());
            }else if(i ==1){
                holder.stextview.setText(det.getImgname());
                holder.secondimage.setBackgroundResource(det.getImgid());
            }else if(i ==2){
                holder.thirdimage.setBackgroundResource(det.getImgid());
                holder.ttextview.setText(det.getImgname());
            }else if(i==3){
                holder.fourthimage.setBackgroundResource(det.getImgid());
                holder.ftextview.setText(det.getImgname());
            }
        }
    return convertView;
    }

    /** View holder for the views we need access to */
    private static class Holder {
        public TextView textview;
        public TextView stextview;
        public TextView ttextview;
        public TextView ftextview;

        public TableRow trow;
        public TableRow trow2;
        public ImageView image;
        public ImageView secondimage;
        public ImageView thirdimage;
        public ImageView fourthimage;

    }

}
```

But my output is like this..[image: Output]

I want four different images over there. 1. Lion,2.Love,3.Android and 4. Handshake. But i am getting only handshake in all the four positions.I am new to android. Please help me in this regard, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your code has multiple issues, but before to handle them, could you tell us why are you using listview?

Comment: @Okas thank you for your response, as it will be easy to scroll, multiple issues ? what are they. but clear me the output and i will go for performance. Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Details> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Details> item;
    private Context con;

    public CAdapter(Context context, List<Details> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.photo, objects);
        this.con = context;
        this.item = objects;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(item.size()%4 == 0){
            return item.size()/4; 
        }else
        return  (item.size()/4)+1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        /*newpostion = 0 * position;
        newpostion = 0 * position+1;
        newpostion = 0 * position+2;
        newpostion = 0 * position+3;*/

        if (convertView == null) {
            // Inflate the view since it does not exist
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo, parent, false);

            // Create and save off the holder in the tag so we get quick access to inner fields
            // This must be done for performance reasons
            holder = new Holder();
            Log.i("VIEW HOLDER", "Position is" + position);
            holder.lay1 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
            holder.lay2 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout2);
            holder.lay3 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout3);
            holder.lay4 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout4);

            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image1);
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            holder.thirdimage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image3);
            holder.ttextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            holder.secondimage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image2);
            holder.stextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            holder.fourthimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image4);
            holder.ftextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        int i = 0 * position;
        if(i<=item.size()){
            Details det = (Details) getItem(i);
            holder.lay1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.textview.setText(det.getImgname());
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(det.getImgid());
        }
        int j = 0*position+1;
        if(j<=item.size()){
            Details det = (Details)getItem(j);
            holder.lay2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.stextview.setText(det.getImgname());
            holder.secondimage.setBackgroundResource(det.getImgid());
        }
        int k = 0* position+2;
        if(k<item.size()){
            Details det = (Details)getItem(k);
            holder.lay3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.thirdimage.setBackgroundResource(det.getImgid());
            holder.ttextview.setText(det.getImgname());
        }
        int l = 0* position+3;
        if(l<item.size()){
            Details det = (Details)getItem(l);
            holder.lay4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.fourthimage.setBackgroundResource(det.getImgid());
            holder.ftextview.setText(det.getImgname());
        }
return convertView;
    }

    /** View holder for the views we need access to */
    private static class Holder {
        public TextView textview;
        public TextView stextview;
        public TextView ttextview;
        public TextView ftextview;

        public ImageView image;
        public ImageView secondimage;
        public ImageView thirdimage;
        public ImageView fourthimage;

        public LinearLayout lay1;
        public LinearLayout lay2;
        public LinearLayout lay3;
        public LinearLayout lay4;

    }

}
```

I got  the output as follows [image: Output]

hence i got the output..

Answer (score 0):

Ill try to go through issues i noticed right away:

1) handling of variable newpostion

this variable should be local in getView method, it is not used anywhere else

assignments at the beginning of the getView do not make sense

```
newpostion = 0 * position;
newpostion = 0 * position+1;
newpostion = 0 * position+2;
newpostion = 0 * position+3;
```

you are constantly overwriting values, only the last line has any effect.

2) when you try to set values to your views you are getting data object only once outside for loop:

```
Details det = (Details) getItem(newpostion);
```

and then assign the same values to all four sets of views. Instead you should find correct Details object inside for loop and use that (you should check for situations where your items count is not divisible by 4)

3) in the same loop you are looping over all items while you actually you only want to use up to 4 objects

4) getCount() method will return incorrect results when items count is not divisible by 4 - 6/4 will return 1

Comment: ok you are right regarding the variable "newpostion". Ya, now i noticed it. I will check for the count which is not divisible by 4 and remaining things. I will get back to you boss. After checking it.

Comment: when it was three images, i got balnk screen and where as when it was 5 images i got the same output.